# Save base64 encoded image into the file in PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following code :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$data = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAuAAAAI8CAYAAACwIh5dAAAgAElkZJgRCXxOAuIPzzTlg......";       
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/home/Desktop/image.png');
$img = $data;
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Here `$data` contain the encoded string of image in base-64. I want to save the image into the file. I did the previous code also go through lot of tutorial in google but it's not working.

Can anyone help me where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any additional debug information? Whats happening? What is the output? Any errors?

Comment: It showing message `Unable to save the file`

Comment: Where is your UPLOAD_DIR constant? Is the path correct? Did you take care of the needed trailing slash? What is the value of $file? Does your user have write access to this directory?

Comment: ok I modified the path to `define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/home/xpointers/Desktop/');` but same error

Comment: `$file` is nothing but the name of image which is any unique id

Answer (score -9, accepted):

First specify the correct path like :

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/home/Desktop/');
```

After check that the path you provided has read/write permission set or not.

Comment: Down vote for rewriting the answer and selecting it as correct. Oliver's answer was just about it. Maybe better.

Comment: Downvote also for copying the code from Jamund (http://j-query.blogspot.in/2011/02/save-base64-encoded-canvas-image-to-png.html), and not referring to it

Answer (score 6):

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/home/xpointers/Desktop/');
```

Remember! Your apache webserver will run with its own user rights (e. g. www-data). Take care, that your apache user or the group apache runs in have access to your desired directory. To test you can chmod 777 to this directory and see what happens.

Writing inside a user directory is not always a good idea. If possible use a neutral directory where the needed users can access.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this line:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/home/Desktop/image.png');
```

Should be:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/home/Desktop/');
```

Comment: I did `define('UPLOAD_DIR', '/home/xpointers/Desktop/');` but still it showing same message