# Decode base64 jpeg image dataURL and save as JPEG using blueimp jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Class 8.2.3 UploadHandler

Tags: php, jquery, image, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm having trouble editing the blueimp jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Class 8.2.3 UploadHndler file. I want to decode a base64 jpeg image dataURL string and save it as a jpeg image file in the ../files folder.

With non-base64 encoded images, the jQuery FileUpload PHP UploadHandler works perfectly and saves the images as a filetype: "JPEG Picture". When I send the UploadHandler a base64 encoded dataURL, it saves as a filetype: "File", with the contents: "file=data%3Aimage%2Fjpeg%3Bbase64%2C%2F9j%2F4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD...".

I know I need to use base64_decode() on the file somewhere in the UploadHandler. The problem is that the UploadHandler is about 1300 lines and I'm not sure where to use base64_decode().

I've looked at related questions:
[Jquery File upload to database in base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852496/jquery-file-upload-to-database-in-base64)
and
[Save base64 encoded image into the file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10881615/save-base64-encoded-image-into-the-file-in-php)
, which are somewhat helpful. I just need to apply this information to the blueimp PHP UploadHandler.

Comment: b64_decode can't handle data uri's anyways. you'd need to drop off the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` portion anyways before you could even try to decode it.

Comment: Been a while since this was posted, how did you go about solving your issue? Similar situation here.